# how can i pass get values to specific models fields in views.py

Tags: python, django, django-forms

How to pass request.GET.get value to another form in django.

`views.py`

```
def bacadmininvitoBid_views(request):
    project_list = ProjectNameInviToBid.objects.all()
    query = request.GET.get('query')
    if query:
        project_list = project_list.filter(ProjectName__icontains=query)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = invitoBidForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                    form.ProjectName = project_list
                    form.save()
                    messages.success(request, 'File has been Uploaded')
            else:
                form = invitoBidForm()

        args = {
            'form': form,
            'project_list': project_list

        }
        return render(request, 'content/invitoBid/bacadmininvitoBid.html', args)
```

`model`

```
class InviToBid(models.Model):
    today = date.today()
    ProjectName = models.ForeignKey('ProjectNameInviToBid', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    NameOfFile = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Name of File')
    Contract_No = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Contract No')
    Bid_Opening = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Bid Opening')
    Pre_Bid_Conference = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Pre Bid Conference')
    Non_Refundable_Bidder_Fee = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Non Refundable Fee')
    Delivery_Period = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Delivery Period')
    Pdf_fileinvi = models.FileField(max_length=255, upload_to='upload/invitoBid', verbose_name='Upload Pdf File Here')
    Date_Upload = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.NameOfFile
```

i want to pass it to ProjectName field

Comment: what is **ProjectName** ?

Comment: one of my field in another form sir

Comment: please could you also add the form `invitoBidForm` ?

Comment: `code`

class invitoBidForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = InviToBid
        fields = ('ProjectName', 'NameOfFile', 'Contract_No', 'Bid_Opening',
                  'Pre_Bid_Conference', 'Non_Refundable_Bidder_Fee',
                  'Delivery_Period',
                  'Pdf_fileinvi')
```` @PRMoureu

Comment: add it to the question not here

Comment: You can pass the values from request.GET to the next view as context variables and then use those variables as hidden input in your next view's form.

Comment: i want to pass it invitoBidForm @dotslash227 how can i do that, im sorry im new to django

Comment: There's a more robust way where you can you can pass the value from one view to other views, besides from what I had told you earlier - Django Sesssions or Django cache framework. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this if you want to save `query` into your `ProjectName` field

```
form = invitoBidForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.ProjectName = query
            obj.save()
            messages.success(request, 'File has been Uploaded')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Django sessions framework or the Django Cache Framework to pass data from one view to other views, including templates.

Django  sessions uses the request variable. So, you can use the sessions request variable in your views and templates

Example:

```
def exampleView(request):
    x = "some variable"
    request.session["exampleKey"] = x

def someOtherView(request)
    exampleData = request.session["exampleKey"]
    print (exampleData) -> This will return the value of x from the first view
```

Only downside using the django sessions is, that you can only store data that is serialisable, so, you cannot store objects or querysets.

Another, great and efficient solution is the Django Cache Framework

```
from django.core.cache import cache
def exampleView(request):
    x = "some data"
    y = Model.objects.all()
    cache.set("professorX", x)
    cache.set("xmen",y)

def anotherView(request):
    charlesXavier = cache.get("professorX")  --> Will return the value of from the first view.
    xmen = cache.get("xmen") --> Will return the value of y from the first view.
```

You can pass the variables to the context() and other render methods

Comment: thank you sir. i will try this,
how about to another request method sir. for example i want to pass my "query" value from request.GET.get to request.POST?

Comment: You can't do that directly. request.GET contains the data that is sent from GET request and request.POST contains data generated from a POST request. Indirectly, you can.
def someView:
    x = request.GET.get("x)
    return render(request, "form.html", {"x":x})
form.html
<form name="doSomething" method="post" action="/some-view">
<input type="hidden" name="x" value="{{x}}" />
</form>

def someView(request):
x = request.POST.get("x)

Comment: Alternatively, you can store the request.GET data into a cache or session and then recall it into your template
request.session["x"] = request.GET.get("x")

in templates -> <input type="hidden" name="x" value="{{request.session.x}}" />